# Trouble with a simple while loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I'm sorry to be the one to ask a trivial question, I don't like wasting anyone's time. I'm new in the Javascript game and I'm trying to crash course myself in before I start up in school again.

I have a simple `while` loop which is as follows:

```
var numSheep = 4;
var monthNumber = 1;
var monthsToPrint = 12;

while (monthNumber <= 12){
    console.log("There will be " + numSheep + " sheep after " + monthNumber + " month(s)!");
    monthNumber++;
    numSheep = numSheep * 4;
}
```

The first line prints `There will be 4 sheep after 1 month(s)!`
But I'd like it to multiply `numsSheep` by 4, before printing it for the first time (so it'll be 16 when `console.log()` is called for the first time).

I know this is probably a stupid question and I'm overlooking something simple, but I'm stuck here

Comment: Are you saying that you want to print "numsSheep is a multiple of 4" before going into the `while` loop?

Comment: 4 is a multiple of 4, I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: Or are you saying that you want to increase the number of sheep by 4 every month, instead of multiplying by 4? (both methods only yield multiples of 4!)

Comment: I want it to multiply by 4 every month, and I want it to start the multiple on the first console print out, not the second.

Comment: then do the calculation before you do your console.log

Comment: ah ok.. yea whenever you do something like that you want to order your operations how you would like to see them. in this case you have to do the multiplication first before displaying it or you will see the original number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understand your question correctly you just need to do the multiplication before you do your `console.log`

```
var numSheep = 4,
    monthNumber = 1,
    monthsToPrint = 12;

while (monthNumber <= 12){
    numSheep = numSheep * 4;    
    console.log("There will be " + numSheep + " sheep after " + monthNumber + " month(s)!");
    monthNumber++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (monthNumber <= 12){
    numSheep = numSheep * 4;    
    console.log("There will be " + numSheep + " sheep after " + monthNumber + " month(s)!");
        monthNumber++;
    }
```